# SQL Query for a range of values and one single value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query in MySQL to select all columns from a table where the values are between 1 and 10, or equal to 15.

I know it will look something like this, but this is not correct:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_values
WHERE value_id BETWEEN 1 AND 10...AND value_id='15'
```

Answer (score 5):

...`WHERE (value_id BETWEEN 1 AND 10) OR (value_id = 15)`

Parentheses are included for clarity.